# architectural considerations for high traffic web portals

Tags: web-applications, traffic

Can anyone tell me about the architectural considerations for high traffic web applications?

Links to any articles would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Useful Links**

[Best scaling methodologies for a highly traffic web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041457/best-scaling-methodologies-for-a-highly-traffic-web-application)

https://serverfault.com/questions/80821/expecting-high-traffic-on-website-how-to-manage

http://highscalability.com/plentyoffish-architecture

This guide is useful for developers http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/